# My PC got infected if executables of dubious origin were automatically downloaded?

Tags: windows-10, virus, malware

I have a question.

When navigating in page shorteners of dubious origin where there is too much advertising...

And it automatically downloads a strange executable... and I immediately remove it *(through the option of `"Windows Explorer"` that allows you to `"Delete file Permanently"` without going through the recycle bin)* and I never run it.

So... My pc got infected just by downloading that strange executable? Or do I need to run the file to get infected?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Normally executables only infect your PC if you run them. BUT if the site is very dubious, there is always the possibility that other malware made it onto your PC that infects it without any user interaction like running an executable. So you probably should consider using an antivirus software and do a complete scan on all your drives.

And in the future I would recommend using some sort of sandbox if you need to go to dubious sites, like the Windows sandbox which is only available on windows 10 pro or higher, or the now open source programme Sandboxie which was first written by Sophos Inc.
Or just use a VM, if you really expect malware.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have `Smart Screen` enabled in Windows Defender, `Windows 10` is updated to the latest version, as are `Windows Defender Security Intelligence` updates. So... Would a `Full Windows Defender Scan` help to see if there is any type of malware inside my computer? Or would it be advisable to restore my operating system?

Comment: A full Windows Defender Scan will probably find anything malicious, but because in the earlier stages of Windows the Windows Defender was horrible at finding actual threats, so I personnally stick with a commercial antivirus software, but this is probably not necessary. Restoring your operating system would be my last choice as then you have to reinstall everything if you do it correctly, if you just use the "restore" function from within settings, there is the propability of something managing to survive because it is hidden within your personal files.

Comment: But for that matter you should ask yourself how many important files you have, and how much effort it would be to do a real clean install of windows and just install the software you need when you first need it, and store all data on external (and backuped!) drives, which will not only eliminate any malware but also make your PC a bit less heavy and faster. There are plenty of guides out there when to engage in measures as drastic as this, but for that you should either open a new question or do some research in the already existing ones.